# Vue 3 with Composition API: Update Parent Component DOM based on custom method emitted from Child component Update Lifecycle Hook

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm doing a chat widget (a tab system where I have multiple tabs, each tab being a chat) and I'm trying to paint some sort of UX notification every time the user gets a new message from the backend (enduser). In order to do that what I'm trying to do is to emit a custom method from my child component *onUpdate* lifecycle hook that will trigger the parent component event that will add a class to my parent component in order to add a red border every time the final user send a new message.

This is my child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-col flex-nowrap">
    <BaseTranslationBar />
    <div id="chat-body" ref="chatBody" class="overflow-y-auto p-2">
      <ul id="chatBox" class="mt-4">
        <BaseChatMessage
          v-for="(chatMessage, index) in chatSession.events"
          :chatMessage="chatMessage"
          :key="index"
          :chatSession="chatSession"
          :class="{ 'mt-0': index === 0, 'mt-4': index > 0 }"
        />
      </ul>
    </div>
    <form @submit.prevent="sendMessage" class="chat-form relative mt-6">
      <textarea
        class="chat-textarea h-[160px] py-4"
        placeholder="Add your message here..."
        type="text"
        v-model="message"
      />
      <div
        class="chat-input-buttons flex justify-end absolute bottom-0 right-0 pb-4"
      >
        <button
          class="flex flex-col justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring"
        >
          <i class="chat-input-button fa-paperclip fas text-blue-500"></i>
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          value="Send"
          class="flex flex-col justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring"
        >
          <i class="chat-input-button fa-paper-plane fas text-blue-500"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <BasePythiaBar class="mt-4" />
    <BaseChatButtonRow :chatId="chatSession.id" class="mt-4" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, onUpdated } from "vue";
import ChatService from "@/services/ChatService.js";
import BaseChatMessage from "@/components/BaseChatMessage.vue";
import BaseTranslationBar from "@/components/BaseTranslationBar.vue";
import BasePythiaBar from "@/components/BasePythiaBar.vue";
import BaseChatButtonRow from "@/components/BaseChatButtonRow.vue";
export default {
  emits: ["emittingChatTabUxState"],
  components: {
    BaseChatMessage,
    BaseChatButtonRow,
    BasePythiaBar,
    BaseTranslationBar,
  },
  props: {
    chatSession: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const message = ref("");
    const chatBody = ref(null);
    onMounted(() => {
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
    });
    onUpdated(() => {
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
      submitChatTabUxState();
    });
    const scrollChatBodyToEnd = () => {
      if (chatBody.value) {
        chatBody.value.scrollTop = chatBody.value.scrollHeight;
      }
    };
    const submitChatTabUxState = () => {
      emit("emittingChatTabUxState");
    };
    const sendMessage = () => {
      const messageObject = {
        aggregateId: props.chatSession.id,
        message: message.value,
        agentId: props.chatSession.agentId,
        skippedValidationErrors: [],
      };
      ChatService.sendChatMessage(messageObject);
      message.value = "";
    };
    return {
      message,
      sendMessage,
      chatBody,
      scrollChatBodyToEnd,
      submitChatTabUxState,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see everytime the dom of this component gets updated I'm emitting a custom event called "submitChatTabUxState" to the parent.

This is the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul
      class="tag-menu flex space-x-2"
      :class="defaultTagMenu ? 'default' : 'historic'"
      role="tablist"
      aria-label="Tabs Menu"
      v-if="tabTitles && tabTitles.length"
    >
      <li
        @click.stop.prevent="selectedTitle = title"
        v-for="title in tabTitles"
        :key="title"
        :title="title"
        role="presentation"
        :class="{ selected: title === selectedTitle }"
      >
        <a href="#" role="tab" :class="updateChatClassValue" 
        @emittingChatTabUxState="updateChatClass()">
          {{ title }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  ref,
  computed,
  useSlots,
  provide,
  watch,
  onMounted,
  onUpdate,
} from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    defaultTagMenu: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const updateChatClassValue = ref("");
    const slots = useSlots();
    const tabTitles = computed(() =>
      slots.default()[0].children.map((tab) => tab.props.title)
    );
    const tabTitlesLength = computed(() => tabTitles.value.length);
    let selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
    provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle);
    provide("tabTitles", tabTitles);
    watch(tabTitlesLength, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
      if (currentValue < oldValue) {
        selectedTitle.value = tabTitles.value[0];
      }
    });
    onMounted(() => {
      updateChatClass();
      timing();
    });
    onUpdate(() => {
      console.log("updating parent component");
    });
    const timing = () => {
      setInterval(() => {
        updateChatClassValue.value = "";
      }, 2000);
    };
    const updateChatClass = () => {
      console.log("Updating chat class");
      updateChatClassValue.value = "chatUpdated";
    };
    return {
      tabTitles,
      selectedTitle,
      tabTitlesLength,
      timing,
      updateChatClass,
      updateChatClassValue,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Now what is confusing to me at this point is where to trigger the emitted event coming from my child component in the parent component. I don't have a specific call to action to do this because I will need to trigger the custom event in my parent component every time the child component gets updated so I don't know where should I place something like @emittingChatTabUxState="updateChatClass()". I'm adding it at the `<a>` tag at the moment but it's not working.

Comment: It can't work `emittingChatTabUxState` is not an event of the a element, you need to put that on your child component, so in your case put that on your slot, i guess that's where the child component is

Comment: thanks @Lk77 you're right but the slot is my BaseChatWidget component, this is not where I want to trigger the event, is on the BaseTabsWrapper parent component where I need to trigger it. If I follow your approach then I will need my method to be declared on a higher level component which is not the case.

Comment: You can re-emit that event back if you need to